# How show mutual friends?

Tags: php, mysql

I have two tables. Table **users** with fields **id, name, surname**.
Table **friends** with fields **id, user_id, friend_id**
For example, if user with id=7 adds another user with id = 25, then in table **friends** two new columns.

```
id | user_id | friend_id
1  | 7       | 25
2  | 25      | 7
```

How show user's mutual friends?

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stackoverflow. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask - as you can see, we're here to help you with specific programming problems, not to code for you. Show us what you've tried so far, show us your thoughts and we'll help you solving your problem, but nobody is going to write code for you. Please edit your question and show us what you've tried, and we'll help you find your mistakes.

Comment: Please elaborate your question because it is not clear

Comment: are you using Laravel?

Comment: Now I dont use Laravel because I had problems with token. So I couldnt solve problem with tokens. Laravel has bug.

Answer (score 0):

If you have `$user_id` somewhere stored then you can do.

```
Select * from TABLE NAME Where friend_id = '$user_id'
```

This is just a very rough idea. It will fetch you the details of users that `$user_id` has added.

Comment: i have field **friend_id** only in table **friends**

Comment: shouldn't it be: Select friend_id from TABLE NAME Where user_id = '$user_id' ?

Comment: The user_id is stored as a foreign key in other record, so basically we would be needing to check it inside friend_id. If friend_id is $user_id then it means that it is a friend of $user_id and we will get the detail of that person. It would be the friend of $user_id. It will be clarified more then OP shares both his database tables structure.

Answer (score 0):

As your username (**Laravel**chik) makes me think you are using Laravel:

```
$all_friends = array();
$friends = DB::table('friends')->where('user_id', $user_id)->get();

foreach ($friends as $f) {
    $all_friends[] = DB::table('users')->where('id', $f->friend_id)->first();
}
```

I haven't tested it but something like this should get you an array with all users friend id, names, surnames.

Comment: Now I dont use Laravel. I had problems with token. I do faster site using simple PHP. Laravel is useless framework with token bug